# Suddenly unresolved dependency echo-trace-play echo-sigar-libs

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator, typesafe

Yesterday my activator started updating all of the sudden and in the end I got this error:

> Read from stdout: (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.trace#echo-trace-play-2.3.9_2.11;0.1.15: not found
>   Read from stdout: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.trace#echo-sigar-libs;0.1.15: not found
>
>   (*:31mupdate0m) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.trace#echo-trace-play-2.3.9_2.11;0.1.15: not found
>   unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.trace#echo-sigar-libs;0.1.15: not found

Already removed all data in `~/.sbt` and `~/.ivy2` and still got the error. Any ideas?

Comment: 0.1.15 really does not exist: http://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/maven-releases/com/typesafe/trace/echo-sigar-libs/

and there's no echo-trace-play for 2.3.9:
http://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/maven-releases/com/typesafe/trace/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I had to do a git checkout on the "project/play-fork-run.sbt" file on so it could return the line below to 2.3.8 version:

> addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-fork-run-plugin" % "2.3.9")

After that I reseted the "activator ui" command. It ran the whole upgrade to 2.3.9 again and now it worked.

Probably some instability on the repos...?

Edit:

Attaching the github issue: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/1028